# If statement or if specific ID exists in joined table column in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to check if a column with specific ID exists in a joined table and store the result in variable?
I have this model in codeigniter with d.* several results and I need to add one extra variable "response = 0 or 1" to get from joining.

```
function getAllActive($placeid = false, $response = false)
{
     $query = $this->db->select("d.* ");


     //QUESTION SECTION
     if($reponse){
      $query = $query->join($this->table_demand_menu.' dm', 'dm.fk_demand = d.id', 'left', FALSE);
      $query = $query->where("dm.fk_demand", 'd.id');
      **//WE JOIN WHERE ROWS WITH DEMAND IDs EXIST - ofc they will for many cases**

      // QUESTION!!! BUT IF THE ROW HAS A COLUMN WITH PLACEID - used 'having' as example
      $query = $query->having("dm.restaurant_id ==". $placeid);
      //IF TRUE RETURN IT AS 1 IF FALSE RETURN IT AS 0 and spit it out in a variable AS reponse
     }



     $query = $query->group_by("d.id");
     $query = $query->get($this->table_name.' d');
     return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Why is `$response` defaulted to `false` and you are making a loose check, then intend to check if `0` or `1`?

Comment: I see a typo between `$response` and `$reponse`.

Comment: I counted results because there will always be only one row or none...it is defaulted because it is not needed in other places where the function is used...isnt it supposed to be that way ? :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if($response){
$query = $query->select("  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$this->table_demand_menu." dm WHERE dm.restaurant_id = ".$id." AND dm.fk_demand = d.id) AS response");
        }
```

Comment: Where is the explanation in this answer?